# Expectation of 1/Y. Y~Gam

Tags: statistics, expectation

I need to find the expectation E$\big[\frac{1}{Y}\big]$ where Y is distributed by Gamma with parameters $\alpha$ and $y$.

Do I need to find the pdf of $\frac{1}{Y}$ by using some transformation technique or is there an easier way? If not could someone direct me? I don't think I can use a Jacobian, as it is not 1 to 1.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to find the pdf of $1/Y$.  Use the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician):

$$ \mathbb E[1/Y] = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{y} f_Y(y)\; dy$$

where $f_Y$ is the density for $Y$.

Comment: Thanks Robert! The reason why I ask is because when I had to calculate expectation when proving un/biasdness when dealing with UMVUEs I found lots of examples where Jacobians where found to access the pdf of the function. Which was then used to calculate the expectation. Why were the pdfs found for these? Its really bugging me!!

Comment: Be careful with the integral. It does not exist for all values of $\alpha.$